# Google HPIS don't animate gifs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Platform (App Engine). I have a High Performance Image Store [HPIS] url for an animated GIF (example below). I know there are some URL arguments you can provide to manipulate the image, eg `=s1600` or `=s128-c`.

I was wondering if there's an argument to prevent a GIF from animating. Maybe just showing the first frame of the GIF or something. Also, what other arguments are out there?

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fh7nuo67JhRn84I7hQ5hWjsi9e9WaH8Lq3JNUCAWsu5_kcp0HozkGKQO2c3KV_1CN_5cmgs3P0oNY3--Ejp8T9goDMy3Y75cig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Over the years I've been able to uncover the following "extra features" that HPIS has to offer...  the option you want is `-k` which will stop the animation:

```
-bXX           -- border pixel size (border color depends on image color?)
-c             -- crop center
-hXXXX         -- height
-h             -- (without XXX) puts white padding around border
-d             -- download
-g             -- Google+ panorama XML?
-k             -- stop animation
-n             -- crop from... somewhere between top and center?  (requires -hXXX -wYYYY)
-p             -- crop from top?
-rXXX          -- rotate in degrees (90/180/270)
-sXXXX         -- size to best fit
-wYYYY         -- width
-v[0|1|2|3]    -- quality level/file size (highest to lowest)


Other combos:  -hXXXXX-wYYYY-s  -- stretch to fit (only some images will stretch?)
```

would love to hear from anyone else that has uncovered more of these gems?

Comment: It looks like `-` is just a separator, so `=k`, `=-k` and `=----k---` all yield the same result.